# ThreadPoolExecutor clean up when a thread dies

Tags: java, resources, hornetq, threadpoolexecutor, resource-cleanup

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that runs a few core and a certain max number of threads.
The task that is run creates HornetQ (standalone) connections for each thread and keeps them alive while the thread is running. However, we cannot close them when the thread `keepAliveTime` expires and the thread dies. Is there a way clean up resources right before the thread dies?

One way out of this would be using a pooling solution for HornetQ connections.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit vague: "However, we cannot close them when the thread keepAliveTime"... What you mean by that.   I tried to answer you but I couldn't understand the question.. i'm the project lead on HornetQ, I will try to answer you.

Comment: I work with Genti. We are trying to figure out a way (if possible) to automatically close HornetQ connections when our threads die after being idle. We would prefer to keep the connection open to HornetQ in each thread while the thread is active. Presently, we get warnings in the log that the HornetQ connections were left open. It's not bad but we would prefer not to spam our logs.

Comment: If we were able to implement a pooling solution (connections and sessions) for HornetQ standalone that would be great. We could simply return the connection and session to the pool after sending a message and let the pool worry about it.

Comment: If you are using JDK 1.7, you could embed stuff on a closable interface, and it would be closed as soon as out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JDK 1.7, you could embed stuff on a closable interface, and it would be closed as soon as out of scope. We are working on implementing that on JMS 2, but meanwhile you could embed your own class delegating stuff. You will have to keep stuff referenced somewhere in your thread so it will only go out of scope when the thread is gone. (Thread local maybe?)

you need to use try (statement=statement.open()) {}  and auto closeable would be called

Comment: I'm making that suggestion based on your comments. I'm not really sure if it would be helpful. I'm just trying my best to provide you some information. 

If that doesn't help you, keep the communication open and I will keep thinking

Comment: That's a good point, however we are currently using JDK 1.6.0_21-b07. Our company is planning on upgrading to JDK 1.7 so your suggestion is feasible. I leave it up to Genti to determine if we need a JDK 1.6 solution.

Comment: We are actually using ThreadLocal but as Mark mentioned we're still on 1.6. We may address this again as soon as we upgrade to 1.7. I am a little surprised though I cannot find an pooling solution for HornetQ standalone. Seems to be available only on a JBoss implementation. That is why i was going the other direction and trying to figure out if there was any way to clean up at before the thread is terminated.

Comment: You would usually have JCA inside the application server doing pooling. For our client applications most use cases are keeping the connection alive where pooling is not needed.

If you open and close a lot of consumers (which is actually an anti-pattern in messaging.... make sure you use consumerWindowSize=0, otherwise you will be wasting a lot of communication)

Comment: I really don't think HornetQ would be the right place to have a pool. I would rather advice my users to keep connections open as opposed to open/close every time.. which usually tends to make users to think that Messaging Systems are Storage Systems to store and retrieve data.

Comment: We've tabled this for the moment and will re-address it once we upgrade to Java 7.